# whats the simplest way to calculate the Monday in the first week of the year

Tags: c#, datetime

i want to pass in a year and get a date back that represents the first monday of the first week

so:

- If a passed in **2011**, i would get back **Jan 3, 2011**
- If a passed in **2010**, i would get back **Jan 4, 2010**

Comment: What definition of 'first week' are you using? See [this list of definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week_number#Week_numbering)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
private DateTime GetFirstMondayOfYear(int year)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

    while (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: This gets the first Monday in the year, which may be what the OP wants. Note, however, that the ISO has a definition for "first week" by which the Monday of the first week in year N may actually fall in year N-1.

Answer (score 11):

Try this for a solution without looping:

```
public DateTime FirstMonday(int year)
{
    DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

    return new DateTime(year, 1, (8 - (int)firstDay.DayOfWeek) % 7 + 1);
}
```

Comment: int & DayOfWeek aren't compatible,. You need a cast there. Other than that, +1 for ditching loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetFirstMonday(2010)` for getting first Monday for `Jan 2010`. Or you can specify month also with `GetFirstMonday(2010, 2)` to get first Monday for `Feb 2010`.

GetFirstDayOfMonth can get any first `day` for given month, need to pass `DayOfWeek` value for to get result of required `day`.

```
// Common function to get first day for any month & year.
public DateTime GetFirstDayOfMonth(int year, int month, int day)
{        
    return new DateTime(year, month, 1)
           .AddDays((7 - datetime.DayOfWeek.GetHashCode() + day) % 7);
}
public DateTime GetFirstMonday(int year, int month = 1)
{        
    return GetFirstDayOfMonth(year, month, DayOfWeek.Monday.GetHashCode());
}
```