# How do I output the date of all Mondays this year?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, while-loop, dayofweek

I'm trying to output the dates of all Mondays this year, but my `if` element won't work with the conditions I'm giving it.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dagEtt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
    while (dagEtt <= DateTime.MaxValue)
    {
        if (dagEtt == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            Console.WriteLine(dagEtt);
        dagEtt = dagEtt.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `dagEtt.DayOfWeek==DayOfWeek.Monday`

Comment: Getting the dates this year, shouldn't you start sometime this year and  stop sometime before `DateTime.MaxValue`, which is some 8000 years in the future?  And when you find the first monday, why don't you add 7 days instead of 1?

Comment: @Amy It's future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit

```
var start = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, 1, 1);
var end = start.AddYears(1);

while (start < end)
{
    if (start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(start);
        start = start.AddDays(7);
    }
    else
    start = start.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Is it really possible that 7 days from a Monday it will be anything but a Monday? Wow

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know that this is not obvious, and we will have to put up with it :)

Comment: Start=start.AddDays (7+DayOfWeek.Monday-start.DayOfWeek)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the first Monday of the year using the [`%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) operator. This greatly simplifies your loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    DateTime startDate = FirstMonday(year);

    while (startDate.Year == year)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(startDate);
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5665161/3194005

```
public static DateTime FirstMonday(int year)
{
    var firstDay = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

    return new DateTime(year, 1, (8 - (int)firstDay.DayOfWeek) % 7 + 1);
}
```